# Way to store large hashmap into file in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap with 20000 entries. The hashmap is of the form,

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,Object>> mapOne
```

I have method to write the map to file.

```
public void createFiles(String fileName, Map map) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(map);
        oos.close();
}
```

This method through's java heap space error on trying to write the mapOne to file. Is there any other better way to store the map into file for later use?

The JDK version: 1.7.0_17
The map within the mapOne contains unique elements,with frequencies of the objects in the map.

The error message obtained:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.growEntries(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$HandleTable.assign(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at TestIndex.AlignReads.createFiles(AlignReads.java:458)
    at TestIndex.AlignReads.loadInputFiles(AlignReads.java:241)
    at TestIndex.AlignReads.<init>(AlignReads.java:126)
    at TestIndex.AlignReads.main(AlignReads.java:493)
```

Comment: Do you reference the same `Object` multiple times within the map (via different keys)? Or are all references unique?

Comment: increase the heap space

Comment: That should not happen. Is your class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Please provide the stack trace of your Error/Exception.

Comment: The question is "Is there any other better way to store the map into file for later use?".  Please let's not transform it into "How do i correct this code?"

Comment: How are you running your code and what are your Java run time arguments? Try allocating more heap space using `-Xmx`.

Comment: I use eclipse IDE with standard java heap size.

Comment: In your Eclipse goto `Run -> Run Configuration` and open this particular Java Application. Then click on Arguments and add `-Xmx2048M` and run your application. See how it behaves then.

Comment: I tried running the application with the -Xmx2048M ,thanks the program excutes without any error. The file it generated was of size 177MB. But with this heap space config,makes an mandate requirement for systems to have memory to run this app. Is there any other way to over come it?

Comment: @Balaram26: This is a standard practice to allocate more heap to JVM if needed. You can release your app with the instructions to allocate more heap, there is nothing unusual in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a very large HashMap.  You should consider increasing heap ("memory") size when invoking your program.  In the case of Oracle's JDK version 1.7.0_17, this can be done with command line switches `-Xms1g -Xmx1g` .  This example sets the maximum heap to 1 GB.  For it to became fully effective, the machine has to have (virtual) memory resources enough, of course.  The default value can be as little as 64 MB (less than 10% of 1 GB), depending on the exact conditions.

Regarding, your second question, you need to specify what you consider "better".  That said, using the standard object serialization API as you are doing is the best option in most cases.

The second most common alternative (some could say it's really the first), is to store information in a database and construct objects from that information as required.  Obviously, if for some reason you need all the information in memory at the same time, you have not advanced much.

The third alternative (valid in case for some reason object serialization API was misbehaving in this particular case (which I doubt)), is not to serialize the whole map, but each element at a time.  Or even each data item.  This requires you to define an application-specific serialization protocol on top of the standard API.  Not extremely difficult, but probably meriting a separate question.

Comment: But each entry is itself a map, so it could be large indeed.

Comment: I tested with two different object parameters,the object with more parameters causes the heap space error,where as the object with less parameters doesn't through any error.

Comment: @Bohemian  You are right there.  I hadn't noticed.  However, the serialization API doesn't use much more heap than the original object hierarchy.  The OP is close to the limit anyways.

Comment: @Balaram26  What is your JVM?  What heap sizes have you tried?

Comment: I dint change the standard java heap size.

Comment: And what is your JVM?  Oracle's hotspot?  IBM's?  Oracle jrockIt?  There is no universal default heap size.

Comment: @Balaram26  As you added JVM version, I modified the answer to indicate how to expand heap assignment.

Comment: 0.1% of 1 GB is not even remotely close to 64 MB... Not sure what that statement is about...? Also, the JVM default is based on the systems installed memory.

Comment: @Xabster  Review your math skills, including rounding to one decimal.  Otherwise than that, I reworded my response to account for your other comment.  For an obviously inexperienced user the original text seemed enough.  I just wanted to convince him to try expanding the heap (which he finally did, and it solved his/her problem, at least temporarily).  Lazy me!  With just a few extra words the sentence could have also be all precise and correct!  Thanks for helping making this a better answer.

Comment: @MarioRossi: my math skills? I guess you also mean google's math skills and any calculator on the planet... 0.1% of 1GB is 1 MB. 64MB is 6.4% of 1 GB, that means you're off by a factor 64.

Comment: @Xabster You are absolutely right. I meant 0.1, which is 10%. I apologize profusely for this.  Above everything, for the tone of my comment. I corrected my answer, and, again, thanks a lot for helping me making it a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are serializing objects that reference large objects that you do not want to be serialized. Example taken from the [java.awt.Component javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html):

> Developers will need, as always, to consider the implications of
>   making an object serializable. One situation to watch out for is this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

class MyApp implements ActionListener, Serializable
{
    BigObjectThatShouldNotBeSerializedWithAButton bigOne;
    Button aButton = new Button();

    MyApp()
    {
        // Oops, now aButton has a listener with a reference
        // to bigOne!
        aButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello There");
    }
}
```

> In this example, serializing aButton by itself will cause MyApp and everything it refers to to be serialized as well. The
>   problem is that the listener is serializable by coincidence, not by
>   design.